# Library not loaded: '@rpath/Starscream.framework/Starscream'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit, xcframework

```
dyld[45267]: Library not loaded: '@rpath/Starscream.framework/Starscream'
  Referenced from: '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/048F8320-9DE3-45C1-9A5A-1E9C4A893C8E/Roam Example.app/Roam Example'
  Reason: tried: '/usr/lib/swift/Starscream.framework/Starscream' (no such file), '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/048F8320-9DE3-45C1-9A5A-1E9C4A893C8E/Roam Example.app/Frameworks/Starscream.framework/Starscream' (no such file), '/usr/lib/swift/Starscream.framework/Starscream' (no such file), '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/048F8320-9DE3-45C1-9A5A-1E9C4A893C8E/Roam Example.app/Frameworks/Starscream.framework/Starscream' (no such file), '/System/Library/Frameworks/Starscream.framework/Starscream' (no such file)
Library not loaded: '@rpath/Starscream.framework/Starscream'
  Referenced from: '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/048F8320-9DE3-45C1-9A5A-1E9C4A893C8E/Roam Example.app/Roam Example'
  Reason: tried: '/usr/lib/swift/Starscream.framework/Starscream' (no such file), '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/048F8320-9DE3-45C1-9A5A-1E9C4A893C8E/Roam Example.app/Frameworks/Starscream.framework/Starscream' (no such file), '/usr/lib/swift/Starscream.framework/Starscream' (no such file), '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/048F8320-9DE3-45C1-9A5A-1E9C4A893C8E/Roam Example.app/Frameworks/Starscream.framework/Starscream' (no such file), '/System/Library/Frameworks/Starscream.framework/Starscream' (no such file)
```

I have added the framework and select embed and signing.
Can anyone help to resolve this

[image]